# I keep getting logged out by router's captive portal

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, login, captive-portal

I live in a condo with building-managed WiFi (Mikrotik router) with a captive login portal, and lately I keep getting "logged out" every few minutes.

What happens is I try to go to some `https` URL, like `https://google.com`, and I get

```
This site can’t be reached. www.google.com unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

Then I have to go to a `http` URL, like `http://www.aftonbladet.se`, and that brings me to a router page that says

```
You are logged in. If nothing happens, click here.
```

After a second or two, I'm redirected to `http://www.aftonbladet.se`, and I can access `https://google.com`- until I'm logged out the next time.

One thing I find strange about this is that I usually don't have to actually log in to the captive portal (enter username and password), it's usually enough just to visit a `http` URL and that seems to log me in automatically.

I have tried some different solutions - constantly pinging a server, using cUrl to fetch a webpage every 30 seconds - but they don't seem to work.

Is there any hope of resolving this without having to ask the building management to replace the routers (which they most likely won't)?

Comment: You would have to connect your own router, to the building's access point, if you don't want to report the broken hardware to the building mangement

Comment: If it's their router, it's their responsibility to fix it, or keep it working. You can't really do anything to it anyway since it's not really yours, they'd probably be upset if you tried changing it. I'm assuming you're paying for this internet access too? Ask them for a credit while you're complaining about being kicked off every minute, it must make the internet practically unusable, so tell them so..... Also, what use is a wifi login page that never asks you to log in? It's not impossibly paranoid to think it could be a rogue / fake "honeypot" trying to get you to connect through them...?

Comment: @Xen2050 Will have a talk with management and see what they say, the problem is I'm subletting the place, and it's in Thailand - speaking from experience, the usual sequence of events is "Me: Excuse me, this thing is broken. Repair guy: Ok I'll fix it. ...wait... Repair guy: Okay it's fixed. Me: No it's not, the problem is still there? Repair guy: Oh... then it's not a problem. See ya!" :/ Extra funny when you actually watch someone work and see that they literally did nothing to fix the problem, but still consider it "fixed". About the login, I guess it might be using cookies or something?

Comment: Well there's your problem ;-) In that case I'd try things like getting as close to the router as possible, a bigger antenna, watch for interference (microwaves, big metal things, electrical noise). I'm not sure how or if you could force a reboot on the router (or if that would require any sort of admin login before it would start working OK again), maybe a power switch or breaker is nearby to turn it off & on again? Trying a different browser couldn't hurt , I don't know what else though